# Highlight specific strings in a given long string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlight

I have a long string, and a list of other strings, which I need to mark in the long string.
Say we have `abcdefghijk` and the strings I need to mark are `ghi` and `abc`.

What is the simplest way to do it in Javascript and CSS? I thought about using the `exec()` method that will return the starting index of the string in the long string.

Then, I'd have the starting index and the size of the string. So, I could find it in the long string. How could I highlight it? Maybe using CSS?

Comment: There's a [highlight plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) for jQuery. The code is pretty short and simple, so you may be able to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [jQuery](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) plugin. It's really straightforward...

How to use it?

1 - Download the plugin

[jquery.highlight-3.js](http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-3.js) (2 KB) and reference it in your page just after [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js).

2 - Style the highlight class

Create an entry in your CSS sheet:

```
.highlight { background-color: yellow }
```

3 - Highlight term/phrase

Call the highlight function with the text to highlight. To highlight all occurrences of “ghi” (case insensitive) that are within the form element, use the following code:

```
$('form').highlight('ghi');
```

4 - Remove highlighting

The highlight can be removed from any element with the removeHighlight function. In this example, all highlights under the element with the ID highlight-plugin are removed.

```
$('#highlight-plugin').removeHighlight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know the index of the start of the string and the length you could just simply put span tags around it. So your HTML would look like:

```
<span class="highlight">abc</span>def<span class="highlight">ghi</span>jk
```

And then you'd style the span in your CSS:

```
.highlight
{
    background-color:yellow; 
}
```

Comment: Yes but this is what to do when you find the strings within the long string. You said you have already gotten the index and the length. Look at @Tyilo's answer which explains how to stick the span tags into the long string